# Extract samples from WAV file in Java

Tags: extract, wav, javasound, sample

How to extract raw samples from a recorded WAV audio file using java?

A website, I referred, contained some sample values like this

As an example, here are the opening 72 bytes of a WAVE file with bytes shown as hexadecimal numbers:

`52 49 46 46 24 08 00 00 57 41 56 45 66 6d 74 20 10 00 00 00 01 00 02 00 
22 56 00 00 88 58 01 00 04 00 10 00 64 61 74 61 00 08 00 00 00 00 00 00 
24 17 1e f3 3c 13 3c 14 16 f9 18 f9 34 e7 23 a6 3c f2 24 f2 11 ce 1a 0d`

Is it possible to extract like this ? if yes, please explain it.

Answer (score 2):

I once looked into the idea of directly working with the bytes in a wav file, and easily found formats and specs by searching. But it turns out that there can be varying amounts of header info that is not raw PCM in a wav file. And it seemed more trouble than it was worth to figure out all the specifics.

However, there is an easier way. You can read the wav as you would for playback (via AudioInputStream), but instead of sending the bytes to the Clip or SourceDataLine, write them to a ByteArrayOutputStream.